# Git: pull vs. fetch→pull

Tags: git

I've never been able to get a clear answer to this question.

For a long time, and at the advisement of a coworker, I've been doing this:

```
git fetch origin
git pull origin <mybranch>
```

I've been told (and have seen) that `git pull` does not behave the same way if you do not first do `git fetch`. You don't get any remote changes.

But all I see online is that `git pull` is the equivalent of `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. If that were true, `git pull` would include `git fetch`, and I wouldn't need an explicit `git fetch` first, right? But that doesn't seem to be the case.

So what I'm looking for is some explicit documentation that describes the observed behavior of `git pull`. (I know I'll probably also get lots of advice to switch to `git fetch` → `git merge`; that's fine too, but I'm really interested in `git pull`.)

Comment: [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull): Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

Comment: Fetch is good for seeing new changes before they get applied to your local repository.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We should probably close this as a duplicate, but before that happens, let me see if I can squeeze this in.

While `git pull` really *is* `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (or `git rebase`), the *precise* difference lies in *how* `git pull` runs `git fetch`.

Specifically:

`$ git pull`

or:

`$ git pull remote-name branch-name`

(or various similar variants) runs, not plain `git fetch`, not `git fetch remote-name`, but `git fetch remote-name branch-name`.

This has *less* difference, since [Git version 1.8.4](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt#L226), than it did before that version:

> - `git fetch origin master` unlike `git fetch origin` or `git fetch`
>     did not update `refs/remotes/origin/master`; this was an early
>     design decision to keep the update of remote tracking branches
>     predictable, but in practice it turns out that people find it more
>     convenient to opportunistically update them whenever we have a
>     chance, and we have been updating them when we run `git push` which
>     already breaks the original "predictability" anyway.

In other words, if `git pull` decides to run `git fetch origin master`, this will update `origin/master` in your repository—but *only if you are not running ancient versions of Git* such as those included in certain unnamed Linux distributions.

If you run `git fetch origin`, you will get *all* remote-tracking branches updated (provided you have a reasonable configuration, which is the default even in said ancient versions of Git).  If you run `git fetch origin master`, you will only get `origin/master` updated, and again only if your Git is not too ridiculously out of date.  Since `git pull` runs the four-word variant, it updates only one, or even no, remote-tracking branches.

Answer (score 3):

> I've been told (and have seen) that git pull does not behave the same way if you do not first do git fetch. You don't get any remote changes.

Usually, that's not true, and git pull pulls the state from the remote.

> But all I see online is that git pull is the equivalent of git fetch followed by git merge. If that were true,

it is!

Citing the manual page of `git-pull`:

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD.

I think that settles it.

> So what I'm looking for is some explicit documentation

```
$ git help pull
```

Comment: Yes, see, but it _does_ behave differently. I can duplicate it all day long. That's what I'm confused about.

Comment: how does it behave differently?

Comment: @JohnAlexander What is your tracking setup like? `git branch -avv` will show you. Maybe your tracking relationships don't look like what people here are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

git pull is a get fetch followed by a git merge.  (or you can rebase instead with the --rebase option).  So no you don't need to do 'git fetch' before a 'git pull'

type 'git help fetch' and 'git help pull' for descriptions

git fetch goes to the named repository, gets the object that is referenced (typically a commit), gets it and all it's dependent objects, and stores it in the named remote tracking branch.  You could then merge or rebase from there. 'git merge origin/master' or you could just view it with 'git checkout origin/master'